# htaccess remove string from url by 301 redirect

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

Need help to strip out this string from url

```
  index....</div></images/myblog_images/978
```

Incorrect URL

```
 http://www.abc.com/index....%3C/div%3E%3C/images/myblog_images/978/index.php?option=com_news&view=detail&n_id=20&Itemid=4
```

Correct URL

```
http://www.abc.com/index.php?option=com_news&view=detail&n_id=20&Itemid=4
```

Many thanks

**Edit**

Hello Anubhav
While applying the htaccess condition - the url is been changed to

```
http://www.abc.com/home/truecar7/public_html/index.php?option=com_news&view=detail&n_id=20&Itemid=4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this code:

```
RewriteRule ^.+?(index\.php)$ /$1 [L,NC,R=301]
```

Comment: Hi Anubhava, ITs showing page error as this webpage has redirect loop. Also - while redirecting it - the url is been changed - am mentioning it in edit

Comment: So you don't want external redirect and still want to show `http://www.abc.com/index....%3C/div%3E%3C/images/myblog_images/978/index.php?option=com_news&view=detail&n_id=20&Itemid=4` URL in browser?

Comment: Thanks, I think it strips out all code before index.php. Hope thats fine !!

Comment: Yes it strips text before index.php Ifv you want to make it more targeted then instead of .+? Use  **index.+?**

Comment: Hi Anubhava, I have changed server to hostgator and this code - RewriteRule ^.+?(index\.php)$ /$1 [L,NC,R=301] - doesnt work anymore. Due to same getting 404 error on server. Is there any alternate way to make it work

Comment: This is pretty basic rule that should work as long as Apache is running. Please check with hostgator admins.

Comment: Thanks, but somehow the code is not working in hostgator /wiredtree / siteground and response from all of them is to check with developer. By putting it in htaccess - there are errors happening on site w.r.t 404 component not found errors